Lifecycle Management of Azure Blob Storage
I am doing some processing related to lifecycle management
I want to know what information the tracking section stores.
Does this tracking work on all blob operations? Does it have any limits?
Please help me with this problem.
Thank you.

fyi documentation-based questions are off-topic. And there's no programming question here. Please read [ask] and post a specific question, showing your work.


Lifecycle Management of Azure Blob Storage

According to this MS-Document, you can automatically manage the lifecycle of your blobs with Azure Blob Storage using a feature called Lifecycle Management.

You can use the rule-based policy provided by Azure Blob Storage lifecycle management to move blob data to the proper access tiers or to expire data at the end of its lifecycle.
You can apply these rules to an entire storage account, select containers, or a subset of blobs using name prefixes or blob index tags as filters.

In the portal, you can add the rule by code view or list view.
Rule:
{
  "rules": [
    {
      "name": "samplerule",
      "type": "Lifecycle",
      "definition": {
        "filters": {
          "blobTypes": [
            "blockBlob"
          ],
          "prefixMatch": [
            "<Your-container-name>/<blob name>"
          ]
        },
        "actions": {
          "baseBlob": {
            "delete": {
              "daysAfterModificationGreaterThan": 60
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

The above rule will delete the blob if it remains unmodified or hasn't been accessed for a continuous 60-day period.
Portal:

To learn more about Azure lifecycle management queries, you can refer to this MS-Document.
Reference:
Optimize costs by automatically managing the data lifecycle - Azure Blob Storage | Microsoft Learn

Please don't answer off-topic questions, especially since this is all covered in published documentation.

Thank you for your answer. However, it is not the information I need. I need something related to "Tracking API", and that's not in the MS Documents.

@Mabataki What kind of tracking you needed?
